# How to specify the path in github actions for creating an artifact?

Tags: github-actions, appsettings

I have created a github actions job to download the appsettings.json file but the github action is unable to find the path to my appsettings.json file.

I have a .net application and my file structure looks like this:

```
[SolutionFolder]
-> .github
    -> workflows
      -> artifacts.yml
-> APIProject
    -> appsettings.json
-> UIProject
    -> appsettings.json
```

This is what I have in my artifacts.yml:

```
name: App Settings Variable Substitution

on: 
  pull_request:
    types:
      - opened
      - synchronize
    paths: 
    - 'UIProject/appsettings.json' 

jobs: 
  syncconfig: 
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest 
    steps: 
      - name: Check out code
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Swap appsettings vals
        uses: microsoft/variable-substitution@v1
        with: 
          files: 'UIProject/appsettings.json'
        env:
          ApiKey: ${{ secrets.API_KEY }}
  archive-build-artifacts:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Download appsettings
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v3
        with: 
          name: dev-settings
          path: UIProject/appsettings.json
          if-no-files-found: error
```

It seems like the syncconfig runs after the archive-build-artifacts job.  I am not sure why.  The archive-build-artifacts job fails with this error: No files were found with the provided path: UIProject/appsettings.json. No artifacts will be uploaded.  The syncconfig job runs and passes.  How do I set my path correctly so it will find the appsettings file for the archive-build-artifacts job?

Comment: That action runs in a separate job, and jobs run on separate runners. Since there is no checkout step in that job, there aren't any files to upload. Do you need a separate job, or could you upload as a step in the first job?

Comment: Thank you for you comment @BenjaminW.! It helped me to figure out what I needed to do.  I removed the archive-build-artifacts job and added everything from the steps part to the first job.

Answer (score 0):

As specified [in the official documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/storing-workflow-data-as-artifacts#uploading-build-and-test-artifacts):

> When uploading an artifact, you can specify a single file or directory, or multiple files or directories.

However, to do so, you need the runner to access the repository structure, by using the [checkout](https://github.com/actions/checkout) action.

---

Here, you are using the `actions/checkout` and the `actions/upload-artifact` in different runners, which have no relation one with the other (as you're using github runner, and not a self-hosted one).

Therefore, you would need to update your configuration, or by using the `actions/upload-artifact` action in the first job, or by using the `actions/checkout` in the second job.

**Example:**

```yaml
jobs: 
  syncconfig: 
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest 
    steps: 
      - name: Check out code
        uses: actions/checkout@v4
      
      - name: Swap appsettings vals
        uses: microsoft/variable-substitution@v1
        with: 
          files: 'UIProject/appsettings.json'
        env:
          ApiKey: ${{ secrets.API_KEY }}

      - name: Download appsettings
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v3
        with: 
          name: dev-settings
          path: UIProject/appsettings.json
          if-no-files-found: error
```